# Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My Android Studio was working fine. But when I tried to create a new project using Master-Detail Flow layout I got these errors.

And now any project that I create gives me the same errors.

```
C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\PopularMovies2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

What should I do?

Here's the Gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lucas.popularmovies2"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use libraries `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1` and `com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1`, try to use `buildToolsVersion`,`compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` = 23:

```
...
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.lucas.popularmovies2"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
...
```

Also, you can change the appcompat version back to `22.2.1` or less

Answer (score 1):

your issue is your compiling against compileSdkVersion 22 but the support libraries need version 23 as your gradle file.  the support libraries work with sdk versions.  So v4:23 means compileSdkVersion 23.  So change in gradle compileSdkVersion 22 to say `compileSdkVersion 23`